# Spring design pattern for common update service or module

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, design-patterns, spring-data

I have a use case where I would like build a common interface or service which can update entities of application. Example case is shown as below:
[image]

Now every application has to handle update functionality of entities. Rather than implementing update functionality in n application module. I would like to build a common interface or server in spring boot.

Service will be like below:
[image]

My question is how to design service/interface which can used for above scenario. Any api or tool which can help me to achieve this. I dont want to write code for update in every application module.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I was thinking about the similar concept to yours, but in Apache Camel framework context. I haven't got enough time and motivation to do so, but your post encouraged me to give it a try - perhaps mostly because I've found your concept very similar to mine.

This is how I see it:

So basically I considered an environment with application that might uses N modules/plugins that enriches application's features, i.e. processing feature etc. Application uses module/plugin when it is available in the classpath - considering Java background. When the module is not available application works without its functionality like it was never there. Moreover I wanted to implement it purely using framework capabilities - in this case Spring - without ugly hacks/ifs in the source code.

Three solutions come to my mind:
 - using request/response interceptors and modifying(@ControllerAdvice)
 - using Spring AOP to intercept method invocations in *Service proxy classes
 - using Apache Camel framework to create a routes for processing entities

Here's the brief overview of POC that I implemented:

- I've chosen Spring AOP because I've never been using it before on my own.
- simple EmployeeService that simulates saving employee - EmployeeEntity
- 3 processors that simulates Processing Modules that could be located outside the application. These three modules change properties of EmployeeEntity in some way.
- one Aspect that intercepts "save" method in EmployeeService and handles invocation of available processors

In the next steps I'd like to externalize these Processors so these are some kind of pluggable jar files.

I'm wondering if this is something that you wanted to achieve?

link to Spring AOP introduction here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop

link to repository of mentioned POC: https://github.com/bkpawlowski/spring-aop